# Windows 10 - Task Scheduler - Proxy Setting / Authentication

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, desktop, http-proxy

All,

I have a simple C# .Net console application calling a external REST API via a proxy configured in browser. The application works fine from Visual Studio / directly run exe manually. This is a windows 10 desktop

When i try to do the same through a windows scheduled task, the program runs only with the option of user logged in. Else when i choose run whether the user is logged in or not under my context - the program fails stating the that the end point is blocked. Either it never takes the proxy or the proxy authentication fails.

I tried to set the web proxy credentials in code, proxy settings in app.config nothing to the rescue.

Has anyone faced similar issue? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Thanks,
Goutham

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar issue, i could create a scheduled task using my account, but not a service account, well when i did the service account would fail to run the scheduled task, it was due to proxy server in our env.

so i was using this line WebRequest

```
 WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("Http://proxy:80");
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxyObject;
```

this for some reason let me schedule the task for my .exe i was developing and not work with a service account. apparently WebRequest is old and should not be used i found out.

so i switch to HttpRequest..

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("Http://proxy:80");
                HttpClient.DefaultProxy = proxyObject;
```

now i'm able to schedule tasks with no issues with svc account or local account, whatever i want :).

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried authenticating via Login as a service?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).